# How to check specified children name included in Parent on JArray with Linq query

Tags: c#, json, linq, json.net, linq-to-json

I have as same as following Json data

```
"widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        },
        "image": { 
            "src": "Images/Sun.png",
            "name": "sun1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 250,
            "alignment": "center"
        },
        "text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "bold",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
```

And How can I check widget Parent node include image  children node with linq ? I have if-else condition if widget parent included specified children node .

if Parent have children property, I gonna feed my db with property data  and run if code block with return true.

My tried query which children does match parent node.

```
if(!((from x in widget[i].Children() where x.Contains("image") select x) is Nullable)) 
     something else..
else
    something else..
```

if Parent haven't any specified children which one I give a parameter with children value, run else block state with return false.

My tried query which children does not match parent node.

```
  if(!((from x in widget[i].Children() where x.Contains("link") select x) is Nullable)) 
           something else..
        else
            something else..
```

But I didn't do when Parent haven't specified children node and run else block..
 Best Regards .

Comment: `dynamic JObj = JObject.Parse(json); if (JObj.widget.image != null) { }`

Answer (score 1):

You don't need query here - just access tokens by key:

```
JObject obj = JObject.Parse(json);
bool imageExists = obj["widget"]["image"] != null;
```

Assume you have follwing JSON:

```
{
   "widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        },
        "image": { 
            "src": "Images/Sun.png",
            "name": "sun1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 250,
            "alignment": "center"
        },
        "text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "bold",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
    }
}
```